# Language Feature Orthogonal?

Tags: language-agnostic, assembly, programming-languages

I'm reading Concepts of Programming Languages (Sebesta 10th edition) and within the text it defines Orthogonality as meaning "that a relatively small set of primitive constructs can be combined in a relatively small number of ways to build the control and data structures of the language". But I'm confused as to what makes a certain language feature orthogonal. Because I probably won't explain the text in all its glory :), I've included below the appropriate text.

```
We can illustrate the use of orthogonality as a design concept by comparing
one aspect of the assembly languages of the IBM mainframe computers
and the VAX series of minicomputers. We consider a single simple situation:
adding two 32-bit integer values that reside in either memory or registers and
replacing one of the two values with the sum. The IBM mainframes have two
instructions for this purpose, which have the forms

A Reg1, memory_cell

AR Reg1, Reg2

where Reg1 and Reg2 represent registers. The semantics of these are:

Reg1 ← contents(Reg1) + contents(memory_cell)

Reg1 ← contents(Reg1) + contents(Reg2)


The VAX addition instruction for 32-bit integer values is

ADDL operand_1, operand_2

whose semantics is

operand_2 ← contents(operand_1) + contents(operand_2)

In this case, either operand can be a register or a memory cell.
The VAX instruction design is orthogonal in that a single instruction can
use either registers or memory cells as the operands. There are two ways to
specify operands, which can be combined in all possible ways. The IBM design
is not orthogonal. Only two out of four operand combinations possibilities are
legal, and the two require different instructions, A and AR.>
```

So my main question is why is it that the VAX instruction is orthogonal. Is it just because it's construct takes less instructions and everything can be completed in a single line? What if the VAX series computers took two instructions and the IBM took three, would the VAX language be more orthogonal? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One vote against stilted language. My view: in VAX the choice of register vs. memory is orthogonal to the choice of arithmetic operator. But you still have to specify addressing mode in VAX assembler to distinguish btw register and memory (I recall). To me it's either orthogonal or not. It's not a matter of degree.

Comment: Opinion: The real power of this design concept is that when you can make two language features functionally independent programmers can then combine them in many useful ways without tripping over special cases. From the implementation side sometimes this also reduces complexity, but not always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Text does not decide if it's about orhogonal languages or instruction sets. With instruction sets distinct feature is addressing modes you can use (or can not use). If you can use all addressing mode wih all (or most) instructions the instruction set is said to be orthogonal (see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set#section_1).